# Trouble running "yarn run" on scripts object in package.json

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg

I'm having trouble using the `run` command provided by `yarn`, Facebook's package manager for JavaScript.

Currently in my `package.json` file I have the following for my `scripts` object.

```
"scripts": {
  "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint --ignore-pattern dist ."
}
```

When I run the following command, it works as expected, `npm run lint`. However, when I run the script from `yarn` with `yarn run lint` I receive the following error.

```
Petesta :: λ -> ~/Git/yarn yarn run lint
yarn run v0.15.1
$ "./node_modules/.bin/eslint --ignore-pattern dist ."
sh: ./node_modules/.bin/eslint --ignore-pattern dist .: No such file or directory
error Command failed with exit code 127.
info Visit http://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

The `./node_modules/.bin` directory is on my `$PATH` and I did notice that if you have an executable like `date` or `pwd` then `yarn run some_script_on_date` will work as expected.

One way to get this to work is to create a separate shell file containing the command you're trying to execute. Let's call it `./scripts/lint.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash

./node_modules/.bin/eslint --ignore-pattern dist .
```

And then run this command on the file `chmod +x ./scripts/lint.sh`

Now in your `scripts` object add the following line.

```
"new_lint": "./scripts/lint.sh"
```

And now `yarn run new_lint` will run as expected.

Am I missing something or is this how calling scripts in `yarn` needs to be done? I would like for to run the command like with `npm`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an issue which I believe is related: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/pull/809.

yarn did not understand spaces in npm scripts. I guess this will be fixed in next release. I can reproduce the issue on my computer (using latest yarn: 0.15.1).

By the way, you do not have to include `./node_modules/.bin` in your npm scripts. Both npm and yarn will look inside that folder by default, as explained here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script

So your script can be only: `"lint": "eslint --ignore-pattern dist ."`

Comment: I tried it with `eslint` and it didn't work that way. The command is not found.

That'll work with `npm run` but not with `yarn run`.

Comment: Literally the other day, lol, the package was called `yarnpkg` and was just recently deprecated for `yarn`. Before this deprecation `yarnpkg run command` worked as expected. Now with the new package it doesn't work.

Comment: Ahh, I misunderstood. Just have to wait for the release.